# Heroku : Using NewRelic with heroku deploy:war approach

Tags: java, heroku

**Heroku** allows the option of directly deploying one's **Java** .war file using `heroku deploy:war` (the Procfile is automatically managed by heroku in this case).

How does one use **NewRelic** with such a setup? The current documentation on Heroku DevCenter on NewRelic asks one to place the NewRelic jar in the root folder of the Java application.

How does one achieve this when using `heroku deploy:war` to directly deploy the app and not via git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received this response from Heroku Support team:

> WAR deploy doesn't specifically handle this case. However, it should
>   work. You can include the New Relic JAR in your WAR and add the
>   javaagent flag in your JAVA_OPTS config.

Comment: Pretty sure it's never possible to point the -javaagent flag to any jar that's inside your WAR file. We'll follow up with Heroku support.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on this question from New Relic support and adding clarifying statements to this old question.  Unfortunately as far as I'm aware, it isn't possible to use the New Relic .jar file in an embedded war file without exploding the war.

On Heroku, using deploy:war simply wraps your war in jetty runner. An alternative would be to deploy an app that uses jetty runner by deploying source code instead of a binary. Instructions are [here:](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-a-java-web-application-that-launches-with-jetty-runner)

If you use the approach above, you should be able to add New Relic to your project.