# Adding newrelic to a heroku war app

Tags: java, heroku, war, newrelic

I'm trying to deploy a war app using heroku and newrelic.
I'm adding newrelic-agent.jar into my war as specified on [Heroku : Using NewRelic with heroku deploy:war approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105865/heroku-using-newrelic-with-heroku-deploywar-approach)

But, seems like heroku doesn't find newrelic jar and I don't know how solve it.

My config:
JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -javaagent:WEB-INF/lib/newrelic-agent.jar

When I open my generated war I see this jar on WEB-INF/lib/

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

New Relic recommends not putting the jar inside your war file because it is not the desired location, it may work but you may also run into errors doing it.  If you want to use the New Relic API then you should be ok to put the New Relic API jar in your war.  Another good place to bring this up would be the New Relic Community Forums https://discuss.newrelic.com/